# java.util.arraylist cannot be cast to android.location.address

Tags: android, geolocation, google-maps-markers

Im trying to put all addresses (Strings) into a list and then get them one by one and populate a map with markers, but i get this error saing that java.util.arraylist cannot be cast to android.location.address. any help?

this is the snipet of code that generates the error

```
            int i = 0;
            List<List<Address>> addressList = new ArrayList<List<Address>>();
            //while (indirizzi != null) {
            while (i <= 3) {
                try {

                    addressList.add(geocoder.getFromLocationName(indirizzi.get(i), 1));
                    Log.i("indirizzo i-esimo",indirizzi.get(i));
                    i++;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i("geolocation","geolocation IOException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < addressList.size(); j++) {

                Address address = (Address) addressList.get(j);
                if(address.hasLatitude() && address.hasLongitude()){
                    latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                }

                markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(indirizzi.get(i));

                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icn_albero));

                Log.i("for", Integer.toString(i));
                j++;
                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the definition , it is a `List` of `List` of `Address`.

```
List<List<Address>> addressList = new ArrayList<List<Address>>();
```

You cannot do this :

```
Address address = (Address) addressList.get(j);
```

As this will give you a `List<Address>` which is not an `Address` object.

1. You can possibly do :

   ```
   Address address = (Address) addressList.get(j).get(someOtherIndex);
   ```
2. Define the `List` as :

   ```
   List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>();
   ```

Comment: i've triend the 2 method you've shown me but then i have to cast this  addressList.add((Address) geocoder.getFromLocationName(indirizzi.get(i), 1)); and it still doesnt work! and with the first method i get an index out of bounds error!

Answer (score 0):

I have Used the below code.

I have called the GeocoderTask class from the oncreate.

```
ed.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
              int position, long id) {
            addresstext = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+addresstext+ "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(addresstext!=null && !addresstext.equals("")){
                new GeocoderTask().execute(addresstext);
            }
          }

        });
```

-

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>>{

 @Override
 protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
     // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
     Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
     List<Address> addresses = null;

     try {
         // Getting a maximum of 10 Address that matches the input text
         addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 10);
         System.out.println(" Inside Background Process");
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return addresses;
 }


 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

     if(addresses==null || addresses.size()==0){
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     // Clears all the existing markers on the map
     if(marker!=null){
     marker.remove();
     }

     // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
     for(int i=0;i<addresses.size();i++){


         Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);
         // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
         LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

         addressText = String.format("%s, %s",
         address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
         address.getCountryName());

         System.out.println(" Inside OnPostExecutemeathod Process");

         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+address.getLatitude()+" - "+address.getLongitude()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
         .target(latLng)      // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
         .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
         .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
         .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
         .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
     map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 18));
      marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(latLng)
       .title(""+addresstext+""));

      marker.showInfoWindow();
     }

 }
```